# EC2 Instance Meta Data on Development Machines

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

On an EC2 instance, you can get meta data from a 'local' web server by doing things like:

```
GET http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```

EC2 also does API key cycling and other magic here. Has anyone built a webserver to duplicate/mock this on development VM's? My Google keywords are failing me here.

Thanks.

Comment: You can record traffic from that IP (try wireshark), and then reply them on the dev environment. But why not develop on EC2? seems easier.

Comment: Because network latency sucks and that also leads to a long change -> test -> repeat cycle. Not sure what replaying the traffic on a dev environment gets me. Wireshark isn't needed -- the 169 server is well documented. I'm just curious if anyone else has already built it.

Comment: I may have something that does this... you want a dev machine to get the same "answers" from 169.254.169.254 that the code will get while running on the production server... right?

Comment: yeah. So if I have code that gets the instance id and records it in a log file, it would try and GET http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id. On a real instance, it would get a real instance ID. On a dev machine, it would return something like i-devmachine. I know I can build it, I just want to know if someone else has done this. I was thinking of creating a virtual interface and running an nginx or apache instance on it pointing at a pre generated file system.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of work. I still think it's easier to intercept the http to 169.254.169.254 on the dev env. Burp Suit is a cool tool for that, and it can reply the mock responses to your liking : http://portswigger.net/burp/

Answer (score 3):

[Announcing Hologram](http://tech.adroll.com/blog/ops/2014/12/22/announcing-hologram.html)!

> Hologram: a system for bringing EC2 Role-like key management to non-EC2 hosts. Hologram exposes an imitation of the EC2 instance metadata service on developer workstations that supports the temporary credentials workflow.